# How to convert quint / qint to regular int (QT)

Tags: c++, qt, casting, type-conversion, int

In my program, a Udp sender, I am working with QT and have to convert the QT-type `quint64` to a regular `int`.

The method `QUdpSocket::writeDatagram` returns the number of sent bytes in the type `quint64`. 
In my program, there will be never more than 1024 bytes sent at once, so there will be no problem with the size of the number when converting to a regular int - which I need to to proccess it further.

What method or function can I use to convert this quint64 integer to a regular c++ "int" integer?

The only thing I found was the "QDataStream Class" documentation (which seemed to contain no such thing) and this question : [How to nicely "cast" qint64 to int for QProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931780/how-to-nicely-cast-qint64-to-int-for-qprogressbar) , but it didn't contain a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`quint64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qint64-typedef) is merely an alias for `long long int` (`__int64` on Windows). If you know that the value fits into the range then you can simply write:

```
quint64 x = 42;
int y = x;
```

However, being explicit is nicer:

```
quint64 x = 42;
int y = static_cast<int>(x);
```

Comment: Actually worked! Thank you! I thought I tried but maybe messed something else up to...

Comment: One further question: what does `static_cast<int>()` nicer - except readability obviously?

Comment: readability and readability and not to forget about readability and last but not least if you attempt to perform a cast that is not allowed compiler will tell you (but thats rather an advantage when compared to `(int)x` casting, because for incompatible types `T x = y;` will also fail). Really, isnt readability reason enough? ;)

Comment: It totally is, which is the reason why my code is "return static_cast<int>(bytesSend) now, but if there is more I like to now ^^